# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null -autoComplit in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an auto-complete field
And I can not get data there
That's the error I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

And that's the code

```
<Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={USERS}
            getOptionLabel={(opt`enter code here`ion) => option.OOnavig.FULLNAME}
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="NAME" variant="outlined" />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: Can you show the `AutoComplete` component? And what are you trying to run `toLowerCase` on?

Comment: In my question I brought the code of autocomplete,toLowerCase is a error I do not know what this is